# How to route my login screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I want to add a login screen right after my splash screen, and then go to my home screen.

```
 const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
Login: LoginScreen,
Home: HomeStack,
});
```

The problem is that my LoginStack is never used even if I call the home screen in my login screen :

```
 <Button onPress = {this.onPressHome}/>

 onPressHome  = () => {
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
};
```

My App.js

```
 render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
                onError={this._handleLoadingError}
                onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
            />
        );
```

Comment: Are you rendering `<LoginStack />` anywhere in the app?

Comment: No I don't. I just call LoginStack via my button

Comment: Okay you need to render login stack to make the button and navigation work. I've edited my answer to give you more details. Let me know if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using `React Navigation` for the routing. You can pass a 2nd argument to the `createStackNavigator` which is the config for the [Stack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig).

if you pass an object to the stack you can define which screen you want. So your code would look like:

```
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({ 
  Login: LoginScreen, 
  Home: HomeStack, 
}, 
{ 
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
});
```

And then if you use the button as you're using now it should work just fine.

So in your case you need to change your `App.js` to look something like this:

```
export default App extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
      this.setState({
        isLoadingComplete: true
      })
  }

render() {
    // This is the loading screen?
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
                onError={this._handleLoadingError}
                onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
            />
        ) else {
           return <LoginStack />
        }
```

Once your `LoadingIsComplete` becomes true it would render the `LoginStack`

Comment: It doesn't work :( I assume it's somethig linked to AppNavigator

Comment: How does your render function look like for `App.js`?

Comment: You need to render your LoginStack component `< LoginStack />` for the LoginStack to work properly. e.g: 

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return < LoginStack />;
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you return  `< LoginStack />`  right after `<AppLoading/>`?

Comment: Are you changing `isLoadingComplete` or `skipLoadingScreen` anywhere in the app?

Comment: No I don't. It's just my splash screen

Comment: Check the edit. Add `componentDidMount` to your app.js and then you should be able to see your LoginStack

Comment: sorry, I forgot to tell you that I already have an else case. I changed it with your solution but I got an error : Can't find variable LoginStack

Comment: Import it on the `App.js`
Do you have a expo Snack or some repo to look at the code?